# Code Block getting skewed. Strange behaviour?

Tags: support, code-formatting

When, I am trying to add R output as a code block, every second line is not getting indented, and as a result, they are missing from the code block.

Is this a bug?  If not, can someone explain why this is happening?

[Post in question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/9077/11097)

Screenshots:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no second line in your result. There is just one very long line with a lot of spaces. Those break on the end of the line and then they are showed on the next line.

```
This is the first document.???This is the  document.
```

Here I replaced all those spaces with `???`, and now you see it ends up being one line.

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah, the copy-paste output from R is so ill-formatted!